Containment in BQP of GLHLE (Guided Local-Hamiltonian Low Energy estimation problem)
In the paper 'Complexity of the Guided Local Hamiltonian Problem:
Improved Parameters and Extension to Excited States' by Cade et. al (2022), they define the following problem
[From page 2; last paragraph]
Definition 3 (Guided Local Hamiltonian Low Energy). GLHLE(k, c, $\delta$, $\zeta$)
Input: A k-local Hamiltonian H with ||H|| ≤ 1 acting on n qubits, and a semi-classical quantum state $u \in C^{2n}$, threshold parameters a, b ∈ R such that b − a ≥ δ > 0.
Promises : $||\Pi_c u ||^2 ≥ \zeta$, where $\Pi_c$ denotes the projection on the subspace spanned by the c-th eigenstate, ordered in order of non-decreasing energy, of H, and either $\lambda_c(H)$ ≤ a or $\lambda_c(H) ≥ b$ holds.
Output:
If $\lambda_c(H) ≤ a$, output yes.
If $\lambda_c(H) ≥ b$, output no.

They mention the following problem lies in BQP (page 15).

Theorem 2: (Containment in BQP of GLHLE)


(i) GLHLE(k, 0, $\zeta$, $\delta$) is contained in BQP for k = O(log(n)), $\zeta$ = $\Omega$(1/poly(n)), and $\delta$ = 1/O(poly(n)).


(ii) GLHLE(k, c, $\zeta$, $\delta$) for c ≥ 1 is contained in BQP when k = O(log(n)), $\zeta$ = 1/2 + $\Omega$(1/ poly(n)), and $\delta$ = 1/O(poly(n)).


My queries:
I fully understand their proof for case(ii), as it is a direct consequence of the Phase estimation algorithm. I really don't follow their argument for case(i). It seems to me that the Phase estimation algorithm can't directly help to solve the case(i) problem. I precisely need help in understanding how one can show case(i) is in BQP.
They have mentioned an argument on page 3 (mid section) that seems to imply  case(i) is not (known) to be in BQP.

...  In this case, it is impossible to decide (in polynomial time) which energy corresponds to the target state, and which to the other, unwanted states, unless the target state is the ground state (case (i)), ...

I would appreciate any help or helpful comments to resolve the containment of case(i) in BQP.

Hmm... (ii) seems harder to understand than (i)?  If your ansatz that you can build to do the guiding is known to have a good overlap with the true ground state then you are in case (i), but if it's only known to have good overlap with an excited state, and this exited state is sufficiently far away from the true ground state, then you are in case (ii), right?  The conventional GLHE problem is case (i) but with worse locality and more overlap with the true ground state. But you use phase estimation in both cases on your target ansatz $|\psi\rangle$.

@MarkSpinelli, yes. You got the gist of the theorem statement for both case i and ii. // Now, I think quantum phase estimation is not sufficient to proof case(ii) is in BQP. I even doubt is case ii really in BQP? (May be it's my naive conclusion  :)

Given access to a controlled unitary $U=\exp(-iHt)$, along with any pure (or even mixed) state $|\psi\rangle$, you can always run phase estimation on $|\psi\rangle$, which will always return an estimate of some eigenvalue of $U$, with probability proportional to the overlap with respect to $|\psi\rangle$. The Cade et al. paper is saying that although we are usually interested in the ground energy, if the gap to another eigenstate is sufficiently large and if we can efficiently prepare a state close to this state, then we can still use phase estimation to determine its energy.

I guess you should take their word about the promises.
What I mean is that containment in BQP for both problem (i) - ground state guided local Hamiltonian, and problem (ii) - excited state guided local Hamiltonian, can be shown with the same algorithm; the only difference between the two is that in problem (ii) we are promised a really good overlap $\zeta$ with the $c^{th}$ lowest energy eigenstate.  If either of these promises fail then when we run our quantum phase estimation on our ansatz we could get junk.

In both cases their BQP algorithm has three parts:

Efficient state preparation of a semiclassical state $|\psi\rangle$ with a good overlap with the ground or excited state;
Hamiltonian simulation of the $k$-local Hamiltonian $H$; and
Quantum phase estimation with controlled versions of $U=\exp(-iHt)$.

Each of 1, 2, and 3 introduces certain errors.  Our state preparation might be imperfect but it should get at least pretty close to the respective eigenstate. Our Hamiltonian simulation is never perfect but we can get pretty good by increasing our trotterization factor (at the cost of increasing our circuit depth).  And our phase estimation might not be great but we can improve this with more qubits of precision (also at the cost of increasing our circuit depth). I guess Cade et al., and Gharibian and Le Gall beforehand, made a lot of effort to control these errors. Better control leads to tighter promises.

One problem that I've thought a little about but haven't figured out how to formalize is - suppose we are given oracular access to the adjacency matrix $A$ of a large $d$-regular graph $G$ that is promised to have a (Cheeger) bottleneck.  Suppose we also know that nodes $s$ and $t$ are on opposite sides of the bottleneck.
If we can prepare a state $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left ( |s\rangle -|t\rangle\right)$, then can we learn anything about spectral gap or the second smallest eigenvalue simply by running the quantum phase estimation algorithm on such a state by simulating the Laplacian $\mathcal L = dI-A$ of $G$?  Can we use $|\psi\rangle$ as a guiding ansatz for Cade et al.'s problem (ii)?

Thanks! (Regarding the d-regular graph problem in the last two paragraphs).  I am trying to take a simple 3-regular graph having 4 nodes/vertices. And see if, indeed, your hypothesis for $|\psi\rangle$ holds. \ Just curious to know if you have validated it for some simple instances.

No I haven't - because my knowledge of linear algebra is so poor that I wouldn't know how to even start on even four vertices. I think the amount of overlap probably depends very much on how tight the bottleneck is, though.

I also like thinking about Wang's effective resistance algorithms. He calculates the effective resistance between two nodes $s$ and $t$ of a large graph, based on versions of HHL acting on $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}(|s\rangle-|t\rangle)$. If the two nodes are on two separate lobes of a graph, with a bottleneck therebetween then the resistance presumably is much higher, and this should be reflected in the (second) eigenvalue of the Laplacian of the graph.
